# AngularJs crashes when trying to access data in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, go

So I'm new to Angular and trying to do an app. My server is very basic and written in go. This is my angular code-

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('dashboard', []);
    app.controller("JobsController", function() {
        this.currentJob = 0;
        this.jobs = jobs;
        this.setCurrentJob = function(index) {
            this.currentJob = index; 
        };      
    });

    var jobs = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'requester': 'Prakash Sanker',
            'description': 'I want you to give me the entire world'
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'requester': 'MJ Watson',
            'description': 'Please give me Spiderman, preferably upside down...but Im not fussy'
        },
        {   'id': 3,
            'requester': 'Josh Lyman',
            'description': 'Matthew Santos as president...or Jed Bartlet..but please not anyone Republican'
        }, 
        {
            'id': 4,
            'requester': 'Barry Allen',
            'description': 'A frictionless suit that wont burst into flames when I run at a zillion miles an hour...its for a friend'
        },
        {
            'id': 5,
            'requeter': 'A. Bambaata',
            'description': 'Boombox, prime condition, from the 80s. Go back in time if you have to'
        }
    ];

})();
```

This is my index.html -

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dashboard.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="dashboard">
        <div ng-controller="JobsController as jobsCtrl">
            <div class="jobs">
                {{jobsCtrl.jobs[0]}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This causes this error on my server

```
2015/07/29 12:18:02 http: panic serving [::1]:56857: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 18 [running]:
net/http.func·009()
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:1093 +0x9e
runtime.panic(0x20ed40, 0x4efaed)
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:248 +0xda
html/template.(*Template).escape(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/html/template/template.go:52 +0x30
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, I suggest. You don't do a request, but only try to print an element from your array.

Your server crashes: see: https://github.com/coreos/flannel/issues/242

Comment: Seems like only missing `ng-app="dashboard"` here you can see http://plnkr.co/edit/oV4lRM0n9zOWfKCIy0vC?p=preview

Comment: So did you manage to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use angular's default start `{{` and end `}}` brackets in a go template because the go server interprets your angular as [go template arguments and pipelines](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/).

> "Arguments" and "pipelines" are evaluations of data

To solve this you can make use of angular's $interpolate in your config to change the delimiters that define angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('dashboard', []);

app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[{');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]');
});
```

Alternatively if your pages are static you can just use Go's built in file server to not cause confusion with templates:

http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_FileServer

Comment: is there another way around this? For example by not using go's templates to serve a static page?

Comment: I don't know 'Go', but this is a index.html file, so make it sense?

Comment: so I did that, and now there are no errors, but the output on the DOM is simply //jobsCtrl.jobs[0]//

Comment: @praks5432 if you just want to serve static pages you can just use Go's built in fileserver http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_FileServer

Comment: @praks5432 that's strange. Could you try using `[{` and `}]`? It's the only thing I've used. The implementation with `//` I posted was copied from the docs and might surprisingly be broken. Also you might be missing `ng-app` as Pankaj suggested.

Comment: Why not use $scope.jobs =jobs and then just {{jobs}} in your html

Comment: @KidVeno it doesn't relate to the problem he has, but the reason he's doing that is that when you start building more advanced applications with angular, you begin to nest scopes, which starts to become a mess. To avoid that you instead can use `controllerAs` syntax so that the expressions you want to put into your HTML can be namespaced. That way if two nested controllers have `name` defined you can just differentiate by doing `ctrl.name` and `ctrl2.name` instead of something like `$scope.$parent.name`